# Broadcast vs. Broadcasting

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between the usage of the words "broadcast" and "broadcasting"?

Would it be possible to use "Ministry of Broadcast"? I have found only "Ministry of Broadcasting".

Answer (score 2):

When used as a noun, broadcast usually refers to a singular broadcasting event and not the whole industry or practice.

" I watched a news broadcast last night."

So saying "minister of broadcast" would be more like saying "minister of a transaction" than "minister of finance". If you are looking at 'broadcast' as a a verb, then saying "minister of broadcast" would be more akin to "minister of transact" than "minister of finance" and "minister of defend" than 'minister of defense'.

Answer (score 1):

"Broadcast" is a singular thing, an electronic transmission of information. For example: We broadcast the news as soon as it happened.

"Broadcasting" refers to the general activity. For example, I want to study "broadcasting" or as you said "Ministry of Broadcasting"

Make sense?